# How to generate a function to print char [ ] array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char

I'm trying to write a small function for printing char array that contains **0** in middle and end. My function doesn't print it correctly, what I'm missing :-(
Expected result: **Good-bye0ld0** 
Actual: **Good-bye ld**

```
// call function 
char str5[] = { 'G','o','o','d','-','b','y','e',0,'l','d',0 };
    displayResult(str5);

// This is function 

     void displayResult(string _st)
    {
        int l = _st.length();
        for (int i = 0; i<=l; i++)
    {
        cout << _st[i];
        //printf("%s\n", _st[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: 0 is an eos marker. Use '0'.

Comment: I don't want to change my array. I want to modify my function to print. @JohnnyMopp

Comment: `cout << ( _st[i] ? _st[i] : '0' );`

Comment: Do you want to print a zero or a space to what? A zero byte is a string terminator in a C-style string.

Comment: 1. `<=` in your `for` loop is one too far 2. why are you passing the array as a `std::string`?

Comment: You should use a debugger and verify that the string contains *the entire content of the character array*.  Just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got many issues.

```
char str5[] = { 'G','o','o','d','-','b','y','e',0,'l','d',0 };
    displayResult(str5);
```

There is an implicit conversion from the character array to the `std::string` type.

The constructor of the `std::string` type will *load* characters from the array, *until it reaches a terminating nul character*, which is after "bye".  Thus "ld" never gets placed into the string.

If you want all of the character values to be placed into the string you will need to explicitly call the proper [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
char str5[] = { 'G','o','o','d','-','b','y','e',0,'l','d',0 };
std::string s(str5, sizeof(str5));
displayResult(s);
```

The `std::string` is designed to accommodate all values of a character set, including terminating nul and non printable.

By using the correct constructor, the offending '\0' will be present in the string and you can search and replace it (inside the string variable).

You may want to declare the character array as `const` if there are no plans to modify it:

```
const char str5[] = { 'G','o','o','d','-','b','y','e',0,'l','d',0 };
```

You can also declare this as:

```
const char str6[] = {"Good-bye\0ld"};
```

Answer (score 2):

put the 0 as a character `'0'`. since `'0'` and 0 are not the same. When you simple put 0, you are specifying the ASCII code of the character which is a null terminator character(marker for end of string) and you won't see anything there. And don't forget to put the null terminator at the end.

```
char str5[] = { 'G','o','o','d','-','b','y','e','0','l','d','0','\0' };
```

Comment: I don't want to change my array. I want to modify my function to print. @bkVnet

Comment: @Keihan in that case, check for '\0' and output '0'.

Comment: @bkVnet: your solution may not work since '\0' is the string terminator.  How does one know if there is zero, 1 or many in the string?  Hmmm....

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are right, for the solution in my comment to work, the string terminator has to be removed. That was the reason i initially suggested to use `'0'` instead of `0`. He also need use an iterator to copy the characters to the string in that case.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to check if given character is '\0' and output it as `0`:

```
    if (_st[i] == '\0')
      cout << '0';
    else
      cout << _st[i];
```

also to pass whole array to your function you should use different string constructor, the one that accepts iterators:

```
displayResult(std::string(std::begin(str5), std::end(str5)));
```

otherwise std::string will copy array contents only until first null character

Last thing, if you dont want to include last null character in output then change loop condition to:

```
for (int i = 0; i<l; i++)
                ^^^
```

Comment: There is also problem in the loop condition, it should be less than not less or equal

Comment: @Slava thanx, I was just looking at this

Answer (score 1):

You could write function like this

```
 void displayResult(string _st)
 {
    int l = _st.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
       cout << ( (_st[i]== 0) ? '0' : _st[i] );
       //printf("%s\n", _st[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the character array?   The OP is using character arrays.

Comment: Also, prefer not to use leading underscores in variable names as they may conflict with internal compiler symbols.